# How to select from a table by date using linqq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table with products that can be in different locations to be submited to a rework task, but i need to pick only the most recent one based on the product.

I have the following table:

```
ID         Tag         Location         task            Date
1           1           A                T1              2016/06/01
2           1           B                T1              2016/07/01
3           2           A                T1              2016/06/01
4           2           A                T2              2016/07/01
```

i ned the select the row of the Tags with most recent Date to have in output the row with ID 2 and ID 4.

What is the correct `linq` query for that?

Comment: I have tried with group by, but does not work because all other columns can be different, If it was only Tag column and date it would work  with select max(date),Tag from tbEquipment group by Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `group by` tag then select `max` date

```
var result = db.Table.GroupBy(i => i.Tag).Select(i => new 
                                                {
                                                    Tag = i.Key,
                                                    Date = i.Max(t => t.Date)                   
                                                }).ToList();
```

Updated 1 (Comment 1)

```
var result =  (from x in db.Table
              join z in (db.Table.GroupBy(i => i.Tag).Select(i => new 
                                                {
                                                    Tag = i.Key,
                                                    Date = i.Max(t => t.Date)                   
                                                })
                        ) on new { A = x.Tag, B = x.Date} equals { A = z.Tag, B = z.Date }
              select x).ToList();
```

Update 2 (Comment 2)

```
var result =  (from x in db.Table
              join z in (db.Table.GroupBy(i => new { i.Tag, i.Task }).Select(i => new 
                                                {                                                   
                                                    Tag = i.Key.Tag,
                                                    Task = i.Key.Task,
                                                    Date = i.Max(t => t.Date)                   
                                                })
                        ) on new { A = x.Tag, B = x.Date, C = x.Task} equals { A = z.Tag, B = z.Date, C = z.Task }
              select x).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to get also the Location and ID  for the oone with higher date so group by tag is not working

Comment: Thanks very much. and if my group by needto include also task?